# How can I get Apache2 to serve up .shtml files as Content-Type "text/html" and not "text.html"?

Tags: apache-2.2, server-side-includes

I'm working on a website, implemented as shtml, and when I try to load the home page (http://simplyclassicremodeling.com) from IE8, it says it can't open the file because it transferred as Content-Type "text.html". The page loads fine from Chrome, and loads (with some CSS issues that are not relevant here) in Firefox.

httpd.conf has:

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
```

and further down:

```
AddType text/html .shtml 
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript application/javascript
```

The HTTP headers, from a Telnet session, are:

```
GET http://simplyclassicremodeling.com/ HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2012 21:57:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.9-dev DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
Expires: Sun, 26 Feb 2012 21:57:54 GMT
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text.html
```

Are the "AddType" and "AddOutputFilter" transposed? Based on this information, would you know why IE8 would think .shtml files are being sent as Content-Type: text.html? Is there a way to globally ask Apache, "If you're going to transfer as 'text.html', use 'text/html' instead?

Thanks,

Comment: Who knew IE8 could suck at this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably a bad line somewhere else in the httpd.conf or one of the Included files. I would check the main configuration and others with grep to track this down.

```
grep Includes httpd.conf
grep text.html httpd.conf
```

Alternatively, you can force the type using FilesMatch. Here's an example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(shtml)$">
   # type only
   ForceType text/html
   # type and character set
   # ForceType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Oh, nifty. I had completely missed that in the docs! This is definitely better than my answer. :-)

Comment: ssl.conf declared a type of text.html. Once that was text/html, IE could see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try rewriting the header if the browser is IE:

```
BrowserMatch MSIE
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.shtml$" msie_ssi
Header set Content-Type text/html env=msie_ssi
```

(Caveat: This is untested but I think should work according to the [mod_setenvif documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#browsermatch).)

Comment: It looks like that would set the content-type for everything to text/html, including CSS, JavaScript, and images. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If literally done like that, yes. You could add some extra `SetEnvIf`s. I'll update with an example.